# tablas relacionadas, problema al mostrar un while

Tags: php

Estimados/as tengo una tabla principal alta_cliente que tien id_liquidacion_iva y otra id_liquidacion_iibb, ahi se guarda un indice 1 =si 2 =no, que vienen de la segunda tabla i_sino

el problema esta en el codigo que muestro mas abajo, cuando los dos valores son "si" o "no" osea estan iguales no tengo problema, el problema esta cuando liquidacion iibb esta en si y iibb esta en no...

me podrina dar una mano para resolverlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 <?php

 include 'abrir_conexion.php';
 $consulta = $conexion -> query("SELECT * FROM alta_cliente,i_sino WHERE alta_cliente.id_liquidacion_iibb=i_sino.id_sino AND alta_cliente.id_liquidacion_iva=i_sino.id_sino AND id_cliente = '$modifica'") or die ("Ha fallado la conexión F3");
while ( $registro = $consulta -> fetch_assoc() ) {
 echo '
      <div class="row">         
       <div class="col">
        <div class= "input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Liquida IVA: </span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" value ="'.$registro['sino'].'">
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col">
        <div class= "input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Liquida IIBB</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" value ="'.$registro['sino'].'">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>';
 ?>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué sentido tiene tu tabla `i_sino` ¿? ¿Podrías explicar mejor como se relacionan las tablas? El problema en sí tampoco lo explicas. ¿Que datos esperas obtener, qué datos obtienes? Ya me suena raro que uses campos como `si` y `no` en vez de usar booleanos o, mejor aún, que verifiques mediante la presencia o no (mediante el ID) en la tabla relacionada. O sea, si el ID está ya sería `si` y si no está ya sería `no`

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo pude resolver con la respuesta de aeportugal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando de extraer múltiples datos de una tabla, en una fila de resultado. No soy un experto en SQL, pero así directo sin alguna *técnica* creo que no se puede hacer. Sin embargo es posible creando uno o varios ALIAS de la tabla en cuestión. Una vez tuve una situación algo similar con una tabla Estudiantes y otra Notas donde estaban todas las notas (parciales, laboratorio, semestral) y quería traer los 3 tipos de notas en una sola consulta y lo resolví así.

No lo especificas, pero asumo que estás usando **MySQL** (o **MariaDB**), la consulta debería quedar así.

```
<?php
include 'abrir_conexion.php';

$query = "SELECT TTABLE1.sino AS sino_iva, TTABLE2.sino AS sino_iibb 
FROM alta_cliente 
INNER JOIN (i_sino AS TTABLE1) ON (TTABLE1.id_sino=alta_cliente.id_liquidacion_iva) 
INNER JOIN (i_sino AS TTABLE2) ON (TTABLE2.id_sino=alta_cliente.id_liquidacion_iibb) 
WHERE alta_cliente.id_cliente = '$modifica'";

$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row); // Solo para verificar si son los datos que quieres
```

Como se quitó el `SELECT *` tendrás que colocar explícitamente las demás columnas que quieras traer de la otra tabla (`alta_cliente.honorarios`, etc...)

Comment: Otra cosa, si esa tabla `i_sino` solo contiene los valores 1-si y 2-no, en realidad no es necesaria y sugiero eliminarla o no usarla, lo cual disminuiría la complejidad de la consulta. Por medio de PHP conviertes el 1 en "si" y el 2 en "no", obtenido directamente de la tabla `alta_cliente`

Comment: hola!! muchas gracias por tu ayuda, funciono a la perfeccion!!!!! sos un crack

Comment: Me alegro que haya funcionado. Si la respuesta te ha servido, márcala como "Aceptada". Saludos.